# apt install: Note, selecting 'foo' instead of './foo_x.y.z_amd64.deb' - what it means?

Tags: apt, aptitude

I searched the web but could not find an answer to:

why `apt install ./*.deb` writes `Note, selecting x instead of './x_something.deb'` e.g `Note, selecting 'phantomjs' instead of './phantomjs_2.1.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb'` for packages it installs from local files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `apt` is passing off info to the back end package database and packages can be marked as "selected for install" etc.  This database lists only the package name, which is usually only part of the file name.  The `./x_something.deb` is a filename reference, not a package name, and the `./` part of it is a relative path reference.

A better real example might be for Google Chrome.

Filename is `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` plus whatever path reference you have to it.

Package name is actually `google-chrome-stable`.  The version info (`current`) and architecture of the build (`amd64`) aren't needed in the package name - architecture is controlled by other parts of the package management subsystem, and the version number could/will/would change to numeric, and is referenced in the various `Release` and other index files that the `apt` family fetches (based on `sources.list` contents) and parses on `apt-get update` or `apt update`

```
ivan@darkstar:~$ dpkg -l | grep google-chrome
ii  google-chrome-stable  76.0.3809.100-1  amd64  The web browser from Google
ivan@darkstar:~$
```